# Show that, $2\arctan\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+2\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{5\sqrt2}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: trigonometry

Show that,

$$2\arctan\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+2\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{5\sqrt2}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

There is a mixed of sin and tan, how  can I simplify this to $\frac{\pi}{4}$

We know the identity of $\arctan\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{a+b}{ab-1}\right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Article $240,$ Ex$-5$ of [Plane Trigonometry(by Loney)](http://archive.org/details/planetrigonomet00lonegoog),

$$\arctan x+\arctan y=\begin{cases} \arctan\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy} &\mbox{if } xy<1\\ \pi+\arctan\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy} & \mbox{if } xy>1\end{cases} $$

$$\implies 2\arctan x=\arctan \frac{2x}{1-x^2}\text{  if }x^2<1$$

Finally use $$\arcsin x=\arctan\dfrac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to attack if you would substitute $\tan^{-1}{\frac17}\;$ for $\sin^{-1}{\frac1{5\sqrt2}}\;$.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate, I don't  understand

Comment: @pisquare \ Visualize a right triangle with a leg of unit length and a hypotenuse of $5\sqrt2\;$. The smaller of its acute angles is equal to both sides of my proposed substitution. Can you see that the other leg would be of length 7? (A tip of my hat to Bhaskara.)

Answer (score 0):

Explanation for your question here

$2arctan(\frac{1}{3})$ = $arctan(\frac{3}{4})$ as you already understand

$arcsin(x) = arctan(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}})$[Inverse trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions)

This simplifies $arcsin(\frac{1}{5\sqrt2}) = arctan (\frac{1}{7})$ which makes

$2arcsin(\frac{1}{5\sqrt2}) = 2arctan(\frac{1}{7})$

Now the solution is

$2arctan(\frac{1}{3})+ 2arcsin(\frac{1}{5\sqrt2})-arctan(\frac{1}{7})$
simplifies into

$arctan(\frac{3}{4})+ 2arctan(\frac{1}{7})-arctan(\frac{1}{7})$

$arctan(\frac{3}{4})+arctan(\frac{1}{7})$

$arctan(\frac{(21+4)}{(28-3)}) = arctan(1) = \frac{\pi}{4}$