# If $\tan A=-\frac 1 2$ and $\tan B =-\frac 1 3$, then $A+B =?$

Tags: trigonometry

Answer should be in radians 
Like π/4 (45°) π(90°).
I used $\tan(A+B)$ formula and got $5/7$ as the answer, but that's obviously wrong.

Comment: Why is that obviously wrong?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777652/show-that-2-arctan-left-frac13-right2-arcsin-left-frac15-sqrt2-rig OR 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan

Comment: As there is no angle like 45°,60°,90°whose tan is 5/7

Comment: $\arctan^{-1}(\frac{5}{7})\approx35.54°$?
 https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan+(5%2F7)

Comment: I did a calculation mistake so correct  answer is π/4

Comment: @user466377 Yes, I see, but I don't see what's 'obviously wrong' about $\frac{5}{7}$ being the $\tan$ of the angle

Comment: Alright, I got your point, that's 5/7 is not "obviously wrong"

Answer (score 4):

Using the $\tan(A+B)$ formula,

$$ \tan(A+B) = \frac{-1/2 - 1/3}{1-(1/2)(1/3)} = -1 $$

now use the $\arctan$,

$$ A+B = \arctan(-1) = n\pi + \frac{3\pi}{4}, \ \ n\in\mathbb Z $$

Comment: There are infinite solutions for $A+B$

Comment: Why not 3π/4? or 7π/4, or…? Why arctan, in fact?

Comment: @Shuri2060 I was just listing the principal value, I've edited it now

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping!!!

Answer (score 2):

use that $$\tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan(A)+\tan(B)}{1-\tan(A)\tan(B)}$$

Comment: Hey,Can you please go to my user profile and answer the latest question I posted too?

Answer (score 2):

Use the formula $\tan (x+y)=\frac{(\tan x+ \tan y)}{1-\tan x\tan y}$

And then take inverse

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

> $\tan a + \tan b = \frac{\sin(a+b)}{\cos a \cos b}$

Then

$\tan a + \tan b = \frac{\sin(a+b)}{\cos a \cos b}$

> $\cos (\tan^{-1}x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

$-\frac{1}{2} + -\frac{1}{3} = \frac{\sin(a+b)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\frac{-1}{2})^2+1}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{(\frac{-1}{3})^2+1}}}$

$-5 = \frac{\sin(a+b)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}}$

$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \sin(a+b)$

$\sin^{-1}\frac{-\sqrt2}{2}= \frac{-\pi}{4}$